# Marginal note does not work inside the multicol environment

Tags: marginnote

I am using the marginal note inside the `multicol` environment. `\reversemarginpar` command is used to trigger the marginalnote left and right margin placement. But `\reversemarginpar` command does not work the multicol environment.

My requirement is marginal note trigger left right placement inside the `multicol` package. How to achieve the requirement

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}


% ------------- comment this at the first run -------------
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes\clearpage%
}
%----------------------------------------------------------




\begin{document}

\title{Sample document for endnotes}
\author[1,]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\maketitle

\noindent Patterning\reversemarginpar\endnote{Sample Query Endnote One} in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Two} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).



\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{The sample caption\label{fig:1}}\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Three}
\end{figure}


\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This\endnote{Sample Query Endnote One} auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be
sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling
suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Two} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).  

\onecolumn

\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This\endnote{Multi One} auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be
sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling
suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Multi Two} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).  

\reversemarginpar

\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This\endnote{Multi Three} auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be
sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling
suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Multi Four} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).  

\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This\endnote{Sample Query Endnote One} auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be
sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling
suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis\endnote{Sample Query Endnote Two} in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).  

\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

I will mentioned below mentioned changes doing the default endnotes.sty

```
\def\makeenmark{\fbox{\@makeenmark}}

\def\endnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xendnote{\stepcounter{endnote}%
     \protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
     \marginnote{\@endnotemark}\@endnotetext}}
```

My output and requirement below mentioned here:
[image]

[image]

Comment: May we see some code?

Comment: Do you have even margins?  Have you tried the marginnote package?

Comment: I edit and save my question and provide the MWE and required output. Kindly advice.

Comment: @kormylo auto trigger marginal notes left and right side two column environment and also the multicol environment. if you know the concepts kindly share with me